# MySQL connection error on Mac OS X 10.8.5

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I have installed MySQL using Homebrew on my Mac running OS X 10.8.5. Whenever i start my mac, and try to connect to MySQL i get the following error

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
```

I then run the following commands and then im able to connect

```
mysqld stop
mysql.server start
```

But on restarting my computer again i get the same error as above and have to run those commands again. Any way to fix it permanently ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to have the mysql server start on startup and to do, you would run the following commands:
('5.6.10' is mysql version number. if you use another version, change it)

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.10/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```